# How do I correctly add tooltip as a hover over button in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is the ASP

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="button" ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="~/Images/lock.png" text="Lock Customer" CommandName="lock" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Image" ImageUrl="~/Images/lock_open.png" CommandName="unlock" runat="server" />
```

I did it two different ways based on research. The  works, but I cannot get the tooltip to work.

the  works, but when I press it to perform "lock" command, I get the following error:

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format
```

Here is the cs:

```
Queries Q = new Queries();

string cmd = e.CommandName.ToString();
if (cmd == "unlock")
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    GridViewRow row = Gridview1.Rows[index];
    string arg = row.Cells[3].Text.ToString();
    int c = Convert.ToInt32(arg);
    Q.UpdateRecord("UPDATE [tAccounts] SET [Status] = 'Good' WHERE [contractID] = " + c);
    Search();
}

if (cmd == "lock")
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    GridViewRow row = Gridview1.Rows[index];
    string arg = row.Cells[3].Text.ToString();
    int c = Convert.ToInt32(arg);
    Q.UpdateRecord("UPDATE [tAccounts] SET [Status] = 'Locked' WHERE [contractID] = " + c);
    Search();
}
```

The line "`int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)` ... e.CommandArgument is NULL on `cmd == lock`, but not on cmd == unlock.

All I want to do is add a tooltip to my buttonfield type: image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row index is automatically added to the command argument for a `ButtonField`, but not a `TemplateField` (or any other kind of field). You'll have to do it manually by setting the `CommandArgument` property on your `ImageButton`:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="button"
    ButtonType="Image"
    ImageUrl="~/Images/lock.png"
    text="Lock Customer"
    CommandName="lock"
    CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex%>"
    runat="server"
/>
```

[source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) (see note at bottom of "Remarks")

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at bootstrap, there you can find ways to add tooltips on varoius elements.